# Updating column values of a table in hive using CTE

Tags: hive, sql-update, common-table-expression, hue

I'm a new hive learner. My hive editor does not support update statements. I want to update a column in a table. Let's say I have a table like this.

Input: table_A

| field_description | value |
| --- | --- |
| field1_name | Age |
| field2_name | Address |

But I want to get something like follows. There are more than 100 rows in table_A

Expected output: table_out

| field_description | value |
| --- | --- |
| field1 | Age |
| field2 | Address |

How can I do this using common table expressions? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Insert overwrite method to achieve the desired result -

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_A
SELECT SUBSTR(field_description, 1, INSTR(field_description, '_') - 1), value
  FROM table_A;
```